# Codeigniter issue accessing /admin

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a script that was written using codeigniter.

When accessed using a subdomain http://name.domain.com/admin/ it works fine but I now need to have the script installed in a folder and I cannot access http://domain.com/name/admin/ i just get a 404

I would guess (but I could be totally wrong) that it is a .htaccess issue.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|install|updates|backups|images|css|js|uploads|jPicker|ckeditor|kcfinder|qr|fancybox|test\.php|licence\.txt|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I would really appreciate any help to point me in the right direction so I can resolve this issue.

Thanks

{EDIT1}
With NO .htaccess file name.domain.com/, name.domain.com/admin & domain.com/name all work, it is only domain.com/name/admin that does not work.
When I add a .htaccess as above or the one in the second answer below the subdomain URL's still work but domain.com/name stops working and domain.com/name/admin continues not to work

Comment: Can you please put you .htaccess file code here.

Comment: htaccess added to main question for better formatting

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude also your `name` folder on your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|install|updates|backups|images|css|js|uploads|jPicker|ckeditor|kcfinder|qr|fancybox|test\.php|licence\.txt|robots\.txt|name)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @TonyDeefer I misunderstood your question. I think that I misread there. Is the `name` folder and the 'admin' controller?

Comment: /name is the installation folder of the script, the controllers are all in application/controllers